# need Date Picker Set or cancel listener in Android

Tags: android

i need DatePicker dialog cancel button or set button event listener  so that i can move to specific activity by pressing any button
any help will be welcomed.

Comment: Give more detail for your problem.

Comment: the scenario is that when i click on set button Date picker dialog appears and when i click on "Set " or when i click on "Cancel" i want to navigate to other activity on either click like i m on activtiy B and when i click on set/cancel i move to Activity A

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html

Refer this

Comment: @ BB Expert you are not getting my point this is just to use Date dialog on button listener i  need  datePicker button(placed in dialog) event lister

Comment: @BBExpert is right, Usman just check the point 6.

Comment: You need Readymade Code for this.....
M i right..??

Comment: no got the point thnx @BB Expert and @ Paresh Mayani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

}
```

When Click on set or Done  (in some later OS) this Method is called and simply worked with it to handle my scenario